# Type {...} is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length,pop,push,concat, and 28 more

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this error:

```js
    Type {...} is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length,pop,push,concat, and 28 more
```

I'm assigning album variable to the albumData array. Here is the code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import albumData from '../data/SearchResultsAlbum.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-album-component',
  templateUrl: './album-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./album-component.component.css']
})
export class AlbumComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  album:Array<any>=[];
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.album=albumData;
  }

}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advanvce!

Comment: Either your json is an object, so it won't have those properties that are array properties, or your json data needs to be parsed first anyway in order to use it as array. What do you get when you console.log the albumData?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 album:any=[];
```

use this code instead of the code you have added

Comment: Thank you, but thats' the error I get :

ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'The Joshua Tree'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

For this one I guess:

<mat-card *ngFor="let al of album" >

Comment: You might want to answer @Misha’s comment above..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

By default, Angular doesn't read the JSON file in the application. So we need to do some extra stuff for that. So we will create a file named 'json-typings.d.ts' inside the app folder of the project.

```js
declare module "*.json" {
const value: any;
export default value;
}
```

source: https://jsonworld.com/demo/how-to-read-local-json-file-in-angular